# Trying to get debug working on VS Code for Ruby

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I try to run debug on my ruby file but it keeps telling me this error in the bottom right:

> Please first open a folder in order to do advanced debug configuration.

I have installed the Ruby extensions in VS code.
I have added a `launch.json` file in my `.vscode` folder (not sure if that's correct but I followed some instructions) but I'm still stuck.

Additionally, everytime I try to open/add configuation at the top it gives me this message. I cannot find anyone else running into the error popup message.

Comment: At the moment, your question is missing some crucial information, the most obvious being: did you, in fact, open folder?

Comment: Thats what confused me, as I dont know what it is referring to? Open which folder

Comment: And no I have not opened any folder yet as far as I know. Any specific folder at all